# Querying specific object from a jpa datamodel

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I have a question about querying with an orm mapper like hibernate. Suppose you have a database model like this

```
class A {
    int i;
    B b;
}

class B {
    int j;
}
```

If I want to save an object the hibernate engine can add all class instances at once by cascading queries. This will also work if I fetch an object from the database by value from class A.

But what if i want to have all entries of Class A with holds the objects of B with value `j = 10`?

In SQL i would have something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A a, B b WHERE a.ref = b.ref AND b.j = 10;
```

But with an ORM the ref is modeled with the object references. How am i supposed to create a query like this? First of all: Do I have to write a query? And secondly: How will hibernate resolve these references `a.ref = b.ref`

Comment: any JPQL reference would tell you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate over the references in JPQL:

```
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.b.j = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
A findByBJ(int j);
```

If your tables are properly saved with some OneToOne relation.

Comment: Why do you assume that he is using Spring Data?

Answer (score 0):

Define one EntityManager:

```
  EntityManager em;
```

Then:

```
  CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<A> query = builder.createQuery(A.class);
  Root<A> from = query.from(A.class);
  from.fetch("b");
  Predicate predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.equal(from.get("b").get("j"), 10);
  TypedQuery<A> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query.select(from).where(predicate));
  List<A> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```